# logstash with redis sentinel is possible?

Tags: logstash, redis-sentinel

I want to build a  High availability ELK monitoring system with redis.But a little confuse for how to make redis HA.
Redis Sentinel provides high availability for Redis. 
But i donot find any configuration for this on the document. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-redis.html
So can i use it  for logstash as input and output? Anyone has experience for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash Input Redis  Plugin supports only one host in a `host` option.

I think you have 2 ways to get HA:

1)  Continue use Redis. You can create dns A  record (or edit your host file),  that  will point to  multiple Redis servers, then put the record to `host` option.

2) Moving from Redis to Kafka:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-kafka-intro

Comment: Thank you for let me know it impossible to use redis sentinel.Andyes, i also think kafka will be a nice way.